# Core Bluetooth : Not able to discover Ring Scanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

i am trying to connect Motorola Ring Scanner "R1000BT", the problem i am facing is that when i fire scanForPeripheralsWithServices: , the delegate method didDiscoverPeripheral: is never called.

I looked for similar question but none of them helped me.

My code so far is :

```
#define RING_SCANNER_SERVICE_UUID @"1813"

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");

        NSArray *uuidArray  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:RING_SCANNER_SERVICE_UUID], nil];
        NSDictionary    *options    = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager )central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral )peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary )advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber )RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Found the ring scanner: %@", localName);
        [self.centralManager stopScan];
        self.ringScannerPeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this, i have iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [product data](http://www.generalscan.com/en-us/gs-r1000bt-en.php) this device is a Bluetooth 3.0 device that implements Serial Port Protocol (SPP) and Human Interface Device (HID) protocol.  As such it won't be supported by Core Bluetooth on iOS.

It seems that you are supposed to put it into HID mode and pair it with the iOS device as a keyboard.

The service UUID you are trying to use, `0x1813`, is called "scan parameters" but this is nothing to do with bar code scanning - it is the service that allows control over the BLE scan rates of a device for power management.

Comment: yes , i want to use it as a keyboard but don't know about SSP and HID protocol. How can we connect to devices with these protocols.

Comment: you simply pair the device in the iOS bluetooth settings.  You don't need to do anything in your app. Instructions are here - http://www.generalscan.com/download/Generalscan-Bluetooth-Pair-User-Guide-EN.pdf

Comment: actually ring scanner sleeps after 10 min or so, to avoid this i want to automatically connect the device from my app.

Comment: You can't - there is no access to legacy Bluetooth peripherals from within iOS apps unless those peripherals are MFi certified

Comment: Ok, if my device is MFi certified then how i can connect.

Comment: You use the external connectivity framework but your app needs to be authorised by the device vendor in order to access their device identifier.  This device isn't mFI certified

Comment: Yes, my devices is not MFi certified. Thanks for your kind support.